# How to send email at specific time - time varies?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have an sql database where I store an email message, subject, recipients and the data time when this message has be to be emailed. How can I do it programmaticaly via console app lets say that I hook as an executable via task scheduler?
What should I use - Thread Timer in order to determine when to fire off the email?
Never done this before really hoping that someone can help.
I've tried Quartz but can't figure it out.

Comment: Why you need a timer for this? Set the Task Scheduler to execute the console at specific time, console should simply have the logic to fetch data from the DB and send emails.

Comment: How is ASP.NET related to Console Application? Did you mean .NET framework?

Comment: Kurubaran I can't set the time because every day could be a different time

Comment: @user1932736 How do you decide the time ? Do you have it in the DB ? if yes, Who sets this time ?

Comment: Kurubaran . yes I have the time to be sent in DB. End user sets the time. For example tomorrow we are doing computer maintenance at 7:30pm so i need to send a reminder minute prior to the actual implementation time.

Comment: So have the program that sets the time in the DB also schedule the task. Just have the program execute [schtasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the proper command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to know how to connect to a database, create tables, query the database, send emails, your question is too general to answer it in one post but the below is an overview.

Use a database to hold the email. Make one of the columns in the database equal to the time when you want the message sent. Have the application query the database a few times a minute and if the datetime of the TimeToSend is greater than or equal to Datetime.Now() send the email. Once the email is sent either delete it or move it to a SentEmails database table. This would allow another separate program(s) to drop new emails into the database to be sent at a future time.

You could add more columns to specify things like how often the email should be sent or other conditions that you can evaluate through code to add whatever flexibility is required.

Comment: Smashing1978 - I have everything else.Can you be more specific about this - Have the application query the database a few times a minute and if the datetime of the TimeToSend is greater than or equal to Datetime.Now()... How do you check few times a minute? via Timer Thread? How to make it not so memory intensive? Thanks

Comment: The backend part of this would need to be a windows service - like Ganesh recommends. read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
In the above example, instead of eventLog1.WriteEntry you'd do your database query and send the email. It's using System.Timer to fire the event at a customizable interval. You can change the impact on the database by changing the frequency it's checking the database, every 15 seconds or every 15 minutes, it can work either way.